# How to select top level columns in multi header pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have a multi header dataframe and it looks like that:

```
              SPY                           ARKW                     
              Open            High           Open          High       
               Bid     Ask     Bid     Ask    Bid    Ask    Bid    Ask
Date                                                                  
2018-07-03  272.86  272.87  272.97  272.98  56.00  56.35  56.24  56.63
2018-07-02  269.49  269.51  272.04  272.05  54.87  55.21  56.04  56.09
2018-06-29  272.09  272.12  273.66  273.67  55.58  55.95  55.95  56.07
```

I want to iterate over all top level columns so in that case SPY and ARKW so I tried:

```
for column in df:
    print(column)
```

but it iterates also over lower level columns:

```
('SPY', 'Open', 'Bid')
('SPY', 'Open', 'Ask')
('SPY', 'High', 'Bid')
('SPY', 'High', 'Ask')
('ARKW', 'Open', 'Bid')
('ARKW', 'Open', 'Ask')
('ARKW', 'High', 'Bid')
('ARKW', 'High', 'Ask')
```

How can I iterate over top level columns and then for each select Open Bid column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think loop is not necessary, for selecting use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Open', 'Bid']]
print (df1)
               SPY   ARKW
              Open   Open
               Bid    Bid
2018-07-03  272.86  56.00
2018-07-02  269.49  54.87
2018-06-29  272.09  55.58
```

Or use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = df.xs(('Open', 'Bid'), level=[1, 2], axis=1) 
print (df1)
               SPY   ARKW
2018-07-03  272.86  56.00
2018-07-02  269.49  54.87
2018-06-29  272.09  55.58
```

---

```
df1 = df.xs(('Open', 'Bid'), level=[1, 2], axis=1, drop_level=False) 
print (df1)
               SPY   ARKW
              Open   Open
               Bid    Bid
2018-07-03  272.86  56.00
2018-07-02  269.49  54.87
2018-06-29  272.09  55.58
```

EDIT:

For better performance all values in `MultiIndex` has to be sorted:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful but I have a problem with the first example,  returns: `UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (3), lexsort depth (1)'`. Could you also write code for a loop? I want to make some calculations over columns without making new data structures.

Comment: @MichaelDz - You need unfortunately sorting columns by `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`, so order of columns should be changed, se also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)